# Filter list of values input control base on user role or attribute in jasper reports server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a question about passing list of values input control from *JasperReports Server* to *JasperReports*'s report as parameter. There are more than 100 users which has the same report design layout that I should design more than 100 reports which the same query but different on filter condition.

I would like to design only 1 report and in list of values input control, I will predefine all condition values, but when user login I wish to show only some line of list of values that belong to this user. So that user can view only data that belong to their location in report.

Could anybody tell me how to filter on list of value or other ways that I could pass such user attribute to report's parameter?

Comment: How are you generating the report ?using java etc or just ireport ? will help us to understand better if you can paste the code snipet..

Comment: Hi, i'm using iReport to design report layout. As I mentioned, I deploy report to Jasperreports server.